# Plot_ly function doesn't show a plot in shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am working with R version 3.6.0. 
When I try to build a plot with plotly inside of a shiny App, it only shows a white space. 
Also when I run the plotly function by itself, it is not shown in the Viewer, only when I open it in a new window.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(datasets)


shinyApp(

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot1")),

server <- function(input, output) {

p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')

output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({p})

}
)
```

Comment: When I run your code on my machine it works perfectly. If your question has to do with why is it not visible on Viewer pane, this discussion must be interesting for you. 
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/717

Comment: It is not visible in the viewer pane, but also not in the shiny App. Usually an update of the R version should help, but I already got the newest version.